# Disembarking meeples in scenarios that begin in the sea

Tags: archipelago, archipelago-solo-exp

In the **solo expansion of Archipelago**, there are some scenarios (for instance, the Barbe Bleu) where you start with some meeples and a ship in the sea. Since the rules say you skip Turn #0, the only moment when you're allowed to disembark the meeples when you find land, how are you supposed to move those meeples to the land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an official answer, but it seems that disembarking all meeples after exploring is the only reasonable thing to do. See http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/921800/first-action-when-starting-on-the-plain-sea-hex.